# Hook to change page title

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I want to programmatically alter a page title in Drupal 8 so that it will be hard-coded in the theme file.

I'm attempting to use a hook function to preprocess_page_title, but it seems to not understand what page to change the title on.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function test_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == 'node/12') {
    $variables['title'] = 'New Title';
  }
}
```

I figured the only way to make this change on one specific page is to set the node argument. Has any one figured out a way to override page title on Drupal?

Answer (score 5):

In your template.theme file add the preprocessor and then override page-title.html.twig in your template folder by printing the variable, like below:

```
function theme_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
  $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
  $nid = $node->id();
  if($nid == '14') {
    $variables['subtitle'] = 'Subheading';
  }
}
```

then {{ subtitle }}

Answer (score 2):

Here's the method to preprocess your page :

```
function yourthemename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if ($node) {
    $variables['title'] = $node->getTitle();
  }
}
```

and in your template page.html.twig

```
{{title}}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of solutions to change the page title

**On template**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
     function MYMODULE_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {

      if ($YOUR_LOGIC == TRUE) {
          $variables['title'] = 'New Title';
     }
     }
```

**On the node view page**

```
/**
* Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter().
*/
function mymodule_user_view_alter(array &$build, Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
      if ($YOUR_LOGIC == TRUE) {
  $build['#title'] = $entity->get('field_display_name')->getString();
  }
}
```

*for a sample if you want to change user title*

```
function mymodule_user_view_alter(array &$build, Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
    if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'user') {  
  $build['#title'] = $entity->get('field_first_name')->getString();
  }
}
```

**On Controller or hook_form_alter**

```
if ($YOUR_LOGIC == TRUE) {
$request = \Drupal::request();
if ($route = $request->attributes->get(\Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_OBJECT)) {
  $route->setDefault('_title', 'New Title');
 }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Page Title is a block in Drupal 8. If you can find the `plugin_id` of the page title block (which is likely to be `page_title_block`), then you can override the title directly, with no need to change an existing twig template, using a block preprocessor. Your code may be similar to the following:

```
function vhs_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  // This example restricts based on the actual URL; you can replace this with any other logic you wish.
  $request = \Drupal::request();
  $uri = $request->getRequestUri();
  if (
    isset($variables['elements']['#base_plugin_id']) &&
    $variables['elements']['#base_plugin_id'] == 'page_title_block' &&
    isset($variables['content']['#title']['#markup']) &&
    strpos($uri, '/url-to-match') === 0 // replace with logic that finds the correct page to override
  ) {
    $variables['content']['#title']['#markup'] = 'My Custom Title';
  }
}
```

The example above uses the Drupal request object to grab and compare the actual URL. The initial question asked to match based on the node path; you could get that with something like:

```
$current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
```

Then, in place of the `strpos` condition above, you could use:

```
$current_path == 'node/12'
```

Answer (score 0):

i have changed the page_title block for user/uid to a different custom account field name like this :

```
function hook_preprocess_block(&$variables) {  
  $path = \Drupal::request()->getpathInfo();
  $arg = explode('/', $path);
  if (isset($arg[2]) && $arg[2] == 'user' && isset($arg[3])) {
    if (isset($variables['elements']['content']['#type']) && $variables['elements']['content']['#type'] == 'page_title') {
      $account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($arg[3]);
      if(isset($account) && isset($account->field_mycustomfield->value)){
        $variables['content']['#title']['#markup']=$account->field_mycustomfield->value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```